# Efficient way of comparing two files and removing partial match

Tags: linux, perl, file, awk

I have two files, example:

File1:

```
partial
line3
someline2
```

File2:

```
this is line3
this is partial
typo artial
someline2
someline
```

**Requirement:**

1. Delete all lines from file2 which contains any line from file1.
2. There must be a partial match, line from file1 found in file2 (not full line match).
3. I am looking for the most efficient way, I am comparing files of millions of lines.
4. It can be achieved with any tool/language on linux.

**Expected result:**

```
typo artial
someline
```

I tested with python but it is extremely slow.
Also tested with grep and it is nearly as slow as python.

The files I am comparing can have up to 10GB in size. Memory on server side is not an issue but I would like not to waste resources.

**Testing results based on answers:**
Files used for testing:

- file1 with 7051 lines
- file2 with 2182387 lines

Using grep:

```
# time grep -v -f file1 file2 > file3
real    28m50.078s
user    27m13.984s
sys     1m36.068s
# wc -l file3
1947790 file3
```

Grep with -F:

```
# time grep -v -F -f file1 file2 > file3
real    0m1.441s
user    0m1.400s
sys     0m0.040s
# wc -l file3
1950655 file3
```

Using perl posted by Borodin:

```
# time ./clean.pl > file3
real    0m2.281s
user    0m2.176s
sys     0m0.104s
# wc -l file3
1950655 file3
```

To be honest I did not expect fixed strings to make such a big difference for grep. So far grep wins this, will have to test with 10GB files and time it. After make sure the results are correct. Will be back with an update.

**Update**

Perl wins this one since I had to introduce some regex for some special cases. For instance I have a big file with domains and I want to exclude those from another file. But that means that I need domain$ as regex, otherwise google.co would match google.com and it is not ok.
If you do not have that special case as I had for some files only, grep is the obvious performance winner.

Comment: define partial. `girl` a partial match of `girlfriend`? and `*` is partial match of anything?

Comment: Yes, girl is a partial match of girlfriend and it should match. I am not using regex inside either of the two files I am comparing. Let's take as a more precise example: domain.tld is a match for somedomain.tld but it is not a match for domain.tl

Comment: Have you tried `grep -v -F -f file1 file2`? The `-F` treats the patterns as _fixed strings_, not as patterns. Perhaps that's faster. Just an idea. It gives the same result for your sample input but I'm unsure about your real files.

Comment: You were right, -F made a huge difference, did not expect that, question updated with results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to build a regex pattern from all of the strings in `file1.txt`, and print only those files in `file2.txt` that *don't* match the pattern

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

my $re = do {
    open my $fh, '<', 'file1.txt' or die $!;
    my @data = <$fh>;
    chomp @data;
    my $re = join '|', map quotemeta($_), @data;
    qr/$re/;
};

open my $fh, '<', 'file2.txt' or die $!;
/$re/ or print while <$fh>;
```

#### output

```
typo artial
someline
```

Comment: This one took only 0m2.148s so it is by far the fastest. I can't confirm the output yet, have to run some smaller tests. Same test files as posted earlier on another solution bellow. Line counts: 7051 file1, 2182387 file2, 1950655 file3. Will get back after I am sure the result is correct.

Answer (score 4):

I would like to use **grep** function on linux system

**command**

```
grep -v -f File1 File2
```

-v : select non-matching lines

-f :  obtain PATTERN from FILE

your need run the above command on the terminal

**output**

```
typo artial
someline
```

Comment: Forgot to write it in my question, I tested it but it is extremely slow.

Comment: this grep function is very useful for small data. so you have big size data. Do you have any particular format for your FILE2 data.

Comment: No particular format, file2 can be anything. And yes, I have very big files, some even of 10GB.

Comment: In file1 you have only words or any particular format?

Comment: slow or not, it's what grep was created to do so it's very unlikely you'll find anything faster as the best algorithm we could come up with to make perl/python/awk/whatever execute efficiently will already by implemented in grep.

Answer (score -1):

Use of hash is a good way to search for a string in a line. It increases your program speed. so you can try this way and see what is your program speed. I believe this will help you.

```
 my $filename1 ="file1";
    my %myhash;
    open FH, $filename1 or die "Error\n";
    while(<FH>)
    {
            chomp($_);
            $myhash{$_}=1;

    }
    close(FH);
    my $filename2 = "file2";

    open FH1, $filename2 or die "Error\n";
    while(my $line =<FH1>)
    {
            chomp($line);
            my @arr= split(/\s/, $line);
            my $flag=0;
            foreach my $id (@arr)
            {
                    if(exists $myhash{$id})
                    {
                            $flag=1;
                    }
            }
            if($flag==0)
            {
                    print "$line\n";
            }


    }
    close(FH1);
```